# I'm looking for a specific idiom/metaphor used in a business context

Tags: idioms, colloquialisms, metaphors

I work in business and I have a vendor providing a service and product for me.

The vendor is self-reporting that what they are providing is correct and accurate (versus a third-party auditor validating that it is correct and accurate). "Yes, we are doing a great job, we promise! All of our work is done 100% correct, trust us on that!"

I'm looking for the idiom/metaphor I've heard before for this scenario, where someone self-evaluating their own work.

This is not the metaphor, but it would be like if a student wrote an essay and self-scored it an A+ and gave it to the teacher to enter into grade book.

The idea is that someone independent of the person producing the item has to evaluate its quality, and one cannot simply trust the producer to truthfully grade herself.

Comment: Are looking for something like "that's like giving the fox the key to the henhouse"? Or just "conflict of interest" or "trust but verify"

Comment: The fox and the henhouse is the metaphor I was looking for. If you post it as an answer, I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

**self-praise is no praise**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/self-praise+is+no+praise+(at+all)) an idiom

> praise of oneself is inherently worthless or dubious, as one cannot be
>   objective of one's own work or accomplishments.

As in:

> So many companies claim to be the best in the business at this or that
>   in their marketing, but **self-praise is no praise**, so I can never take
>   them seriously.

Like self-assertion, the act of putting forth your own opinions in a boastful or inconsiderate manner that implies you feel superior to others works for some, but in business it sows doubt.